# Confuse to Use AlarmManager on Android Studio

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reminders

i am a newbie in android programming and this my first app that i want to develop.
I try to make an app that can store input and output cashflow and also have a reminder.
But i stuck in this reminder. I want to make a reminder that user can set when they will input something in the app.
Example : when i want to pay my credit card on 21st November, then i will make a reminder inside the app and the reminder will come to the notification on 21st November to remind me pay my credit card.

So my question, what method can i use for it? I try to use alarm manager but i still confuse. 
Please master help me
Thanks before.

Comment: What is your confuse about `AlarmManager`?

Comment: exactly i don't know is the AlarmManager match with my needs on the app?